# what is difference between Push notification and cloud message?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

what is difference between Push notification and cloud message?

is registration id and device id store in third party ?

Answer (score 0):

*Push Notification* is a notification that appears on a client app, usually like a popup, that is *pushed* from a server. That's it. Pretty straightforward. You could also check out this [searchmobilecomputing link](https://searchmobilecomputing.techtarget.com/definition/push-notification) for a good explanation, or even just doing a quick Google search would return you a lot information about Push Notification.

*Cloud Message* on the other hand is something vague. If you're referring to the *Cloud Messaging* in *Google Cloud Messaging*, then I believe you're giving it too much thought. Google Cloud Messaging (now known as [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)) is the name of Google's free push notification service.

For the registration token, I believe Google stores a copy of the tokens on their end, ***but*** doesn't keep track of them. It is the developer's responsibility to keep track of the tokens i.e. storing them in a trusted and secure server.